# How do I open a certain file location in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

Using Windows PowerShell, is there a shorter way of opening a program other than the following?

```
cd c:\program files
cd program folder
start program.exe
```

Comment: Like `start "c:\program files\program.exe" `

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `Invoke-Item` cmdlet and specify the full path as opposed to changing location multiple times to get to the directory containing your target executable

`Invoke-Item "C:\Program Files\Program Folder\Program.exe"`

Answer (score 6):

You could skip the `cd` steps by specifying the whole path, e.g `c:\path\to\program.exe`

If it's a program you launch with some regularity, you could also create an **alias**. With an alias, you could have PowerShell launch `c:\path\to\program.exe` with just `myapp`, for example.

To create an **alias**, use the following command:

`Set-Alias MyApp "C:\Path\To\Program.exe"`

Finally, you could also add the folder location to your Windows **PATH** environment variable. Here's a link to a post detailing how to do this for Python, but you should be able to follow the same instructions for your folder.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7